# Need to use group by, sort and limit for Student list which in return will return the student list

Tags: java, sorting, limit

```
class Student{
    private String name;  
    private String id; 
    private String dept;  
    private String sub;  
    private double marks; 
}
```

need to group the Student list based on dept, then sort according to marks and then display top 2 students
Tried this-

```
Map<String,List<Student>> studlistGrouped = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getDept,Collectors.toList()));
List<Student> sorted = studlistGrouped.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e ->  e.getValue().stream().map(Student::getId).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(0)))
            //and also sort each group before collecting them in one list
            .flatMap(e ->  e.getValue().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getId))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But showing the compilation error for e.getValue()

Comment: Can you add the exact error as well?

Comment: *display top 2* - Do you want the top 2 students in each department? Then is the required result of type `Map<String,List<Student>>`?

Comment: If you just want the top 2 students sorted by mark, there isn't a need to group by department

Answer (score 0):

**To get the top 2 students (sorted w.r.t marks in descending order) for each department:**

The first two lines are same as what you've done i.e, group each student by their department.

From the result map (of type `Map<String, List<Student>>`), this creates another stream from the `Map#entrySet` and collects into another map using `Collectors.toMap`. The *keyMapper* (the first argument of `toMap`) sets department name as the key. In the *valueMapper* (the second argument of `toMap`), it streams over all the students and sorts them by their marks in reverse order and limits to top 2 students before collecting them as a list.

The sorting is done using `Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getMarks).reversed())`. `Student::getMarks` is a method reference which is just a function to map each Student to their mark and do the sorting using the extracted mark field (a *double* value). It uses `.reversed()` to order them in  descending order.

```
Map<String, List<Student>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getDept, Collectors.toList()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getMarks).reversed())
                        .limit(2)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you are doing wrong is sorting on ID.  What you want is to sort on the marks in reverse order with the best (highest) coming first.

Here is a Student `record` with a modified `toString` to hold the student`s information. It behaves like an immutable class.

```
record Student(String getName, String getId, String getDept,
         String getSub, double getMark) {
     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return "%s, %s, %s".formatted(getName, getDept, getMark);
     }
 }
```

Here is some data

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>(
         List.of(new Student("Bob", "1", "Math", "a", 5),
                 new Student("Bob", "1", "Sociology", "a", 7),
                 new Student("Mary", "2", "English", "a", 10),
                 new Student("Mary", "2", "Sociology", "a", 7),
                 new Student("John", "3", "Sociology", "a", 7),
                 new Student("John", "3", "Math", "a", 9),
                 new Student("John", "3", "Physics", "a", 17),
                 new Student("Pete", "4", "Chemistry", "a", 2),
                 new Student("Barb", "5", "Math", "a", 12),
                 new Student("Jim", "6", "Chemistry", "a", 15),
                 new Student("Joe", "7", "Physics", "a", 4),
                 new Student("Anne", "8", "Physics", "a", 8),
                 new Student("Anne", "8", "Chemistry", "a", 8),
                 new Student("Anne", "8", "Sociology", "a", 8),
                 new Student("Gary", "10", "Math", "a", 8),
                 new Student("Gary", "10", "Physics", "a", 10),
                 new Student("Gary", "10", "Sociology", "a", 7),
                 new Student("Jean", "11", "English", "a", 10),
                 new Student("Jean", "11", "Math", "a", 10),
                 new Student("Jean", "11", "Chemistry", "a", 10)));
```

If you just want the top students overall, you can sort the list in reverse order and the just print the `sublist` of the first two students.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getMark).reversed());

for (Student student : list.subList(0, 2)) {
     System.out.println(student);
}
```

prints

```
John, Physics, 17.0
Jim, Chemistry, 15.0
```

If you want the top students in each department then:

- group each student by department.
- then using `collectingAndThen`, sort the list as before and return the `sublist` for the first two entries.
- then print them out by department, and indented by student.

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map = list.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getDept,
                 Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                         Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new),
                         lst -> {
                             lst.sort(Comparator
                                     .comparingDouble(Student::getMark)
                                     .reversed());
                             return lst.subList(0, 2);
                         })));
```

Now print the results.

```
 map.entrySet().forEach(e-> {
     System.out.printf("Dept: %s%n", e.getKey());
     for (Student student : e.getValue()) {
         System.out.println("   " + student);
     }
     System.out.println();
 });
```

prints

```
Dept: English
   Mary, English, 10.0
   Jean, English, 10.0

Dept: Chemistry
   Jim, Chemistry, 15.0
   Jean, Chemistry, 10.0

Dept: Sociology
   Anne, Sociology, 8.0
   Bob, Sociology, 7.0

Dept: Math
   Barb, Math, 12.0
   Jean, Math, 10.0

Dept: Physics
   John, Physics, 17.0
   Gary, Physics, 10.0
```